# call PHP class inside a loop (PHPExcel)

Tags: php

I need to use the class used in PHPExcel five time to change its content inside as below.
But this fails in 2nd iteration.. Please help me how to resolve this ?

```
    for($z=1;$z<=5;$z++)
    {


   class MyReadFilter implements PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter
                    {
        public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = '') {
                            if ($row > ($z-1)*1000 && $row <= $z*1000)
                            {
                                return true;
                            }

                            return false;
                        }
                    }   

    $objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();
    //setting filter to read only limited records..
    $objReader->setReadFilter( new MyReadFilter() );
```

Simply, I need to call `$objReader->setReadFilter(new MyReadFilter());` five times

Comment: you need to define the class and its method. Then you can call the method multiple times. But you can't define the class multiple times.

Comment: @greg0ire : Thanks. Please help to reframe above code

Comment: first step: move the class definition out of the loop (before it).

Comment: then, how can i call new MyReadFilter() inside loop with varying $z ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know what `z` is and when it is supposed to be iterated.

I can think of too solutions, some of then should be good for you depending on what you are trying  to do, but i dont know if you have an undestanding dood enough of OOP, probably you should first study some books or tutorials about the basics.

this is one posible solution:

```
class MyReadFilter implements PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter {
    public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName='') {
        for ($z = 1; $z <= 5; $z++) {

            if ($row > ($z - 1) * 1000 && $row <= $z * 1000) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}

$objReader=new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();
        //setting filter to read only limited records..
$objReader->setReadFilter(new MyReadFilter());
```

and this is another possible solution, if you want to read the file multiple times with diferent results

```
class MyReadFilter implements PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter {

   private $z;

    public function __construct($z){

        $this->z=$z;
    }
    public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName='') {


            if ($row > ($this->z - 1) * 1000 && $row <= $this->z * 1000) {
                return true;
            }


        return false;
    }
}

$objReader=new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();

        for ($z = 1; $z <= 5; $z++) {
        //setting filter to read only limited records..
        $objReader->setReadFilter(new MyReadFilter($z));
  //..whatever else
        }
```

If you know weel what you need, i think it will be clear for you which one you need. If dont, we would need more details

Comment: $z should be a global variable. i need to call `$objReader->setReadFilter(new MyReadFilter());` five times

Comment: it shows syntax error @ `    public _construct($z){`

Comment: use `public function  __construct...`
anyways, im not sure if you know what your are doing. what is the purpouse of calling `setReadFilter` multiple times? whe you call `$objReader->load()` it will only consider the last filter that you set, so probably that is not what you want.

Comment: I want the load based on latest filter only

Comment: if you want just the latest, why do you call `setReadFilter` multiple times?

Comment: Based on following code, filter is set.. if I run `setReadFilter` in a loop, i will get filters based on $row variable..

`if ($row > ($this->z - 1) * 1000 && $row <= $this->z * 1000) {
                return true;
            }`

Comment: Could you please tell me how to print `$this->z` value ?

Comment: yes, you generate 5 filters, but when you load the file only the last one is used, so it would be the same as if you just set one filter with z=5. probably you need to explain in the question with full details what this is for. also, i strongly recommend to learn about OOP, otherwise you will get crazy. 
for printing `$this->z` just do `echo $this->z`. is it not working?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48147/discussion-between-logan-and-carlos-robles)